# Dynamic Jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

This works (in firefox but not ie):

```
document.getElementById(filename+'Likes').innerHTML=result;
document.getElementById(filename+'Like').setAttribute('class','hideGalleryLike');
document.getElementById(filename+'Dislike').setAttribute('class','hideGalleryLike');
```

I thought the jquery code should be:

```
$('#'+filename+'Likes').html(result);
$('#'+filename+'Like').attr('class','hideGalleryLike');
$('#'+filename+'Dislike').attr('class','hideGalleryLike');
```

But it doesn't work. 'filename' always starts with the username of the person who uploaded the file, which in turn always starts with a letter. I am aware of other ways of changing the class, but it seems that it is the dynamic selector that is the issue.

Comment: Code looks fine. Have you tried the other ways to set the class? That's the only thing I imagine could be a problem given your code. Also provide an example of `filename`.

Comment: Post the context. This should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as espected at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bQfE/

So I think something else is wrong.

- Have you put your code in into a `$(document).ready()` function?
- Is the value of `filename` as you espected (`console.log` the var and looks if it is so)?
- If you put the ID into [mothereffing css escapes](http://mothereffingcssescapes.com) and is the JS block green?

Comment: Thank you, jquery needs '_'s and '.'s escaping where as document.getElementByID() does not. Its probably easiest to stick with the javascript in that case.

Comment: @user1192735: Underscores don't have any special meaning in jQuery. Fullstops denote class names. You can find more about in preamble about selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a dot in the filenames? You have to escape them with "\\".